# Why is vertical-align: bottom not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a section of code for the header portion of my website:

```css
.nav {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
#header-image {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height:50%;
}
.header-container {
    height:6vw;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
    <a href='index.html'>
        <img src='img/logo.png' alt="Logo" id='header-image'/>
    </a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='aboutus.html'>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href='activities.html'>Activities</a></li>
            <li><a href='google.ca'>Media</a></li>
            <li><a href='google.ca'>Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I wanted the bottom of the image to line up with the bottom of the navbar. But what's happening is that the image is lower than the navbar. Any ideas why?

Comment: It is because of display:inline-block; which you have used for .nav

Comment: what's wrong with it? I changed to block/inline and that didn't fix things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your list items to `display: inline-block;`

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#header-image {
  position: relative;
}
.header-container {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src='http://placehold.it/50x50' id='header-image' />
  </a>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href='aboutus.html'>About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='activities.html'>Activities</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='google.ca'>Media</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='google.ca'>Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually already set it to that -- forgot to include that code too. Anyways it wasn't working because I was experimenting with a new html boilerplate and it set images to middle by default :( Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav {
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
 }

#header-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
}
.header-container {
  position:relative;
}
```

Use this styling settings may fill your requirements